# How much are our skills worth?

Tags: html

I have someone who wants me to make a website for them but wants to know how much i will charge. I severely undervalue the worth of what i can do as i enjoy it and find it easy. So what would be a fair price for a website consisting of 5 basic html pages and 45+ catalog pages (images, descriptions and item code)? These will be written in HTML and CSS
Thanks

Comment: charge with your per hour rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:  About $60 per hour on the low end, $120+ on the high end.

Longer answer:  http://procnew.com/freelance-consulting-rates.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic answer to your question. Be dispassionate about it. Research the going market rate in your area for such a job and charge a bit under that if you are not seasoned (but still very competent.)

If you are accomplished, charge whatever you feel you need to. : )